# MRAID file reference

Tags: javascript

The IAB MRAID specification
http://www.iab.net/media/file/IAB_MRAID_VersionOne_final.pdf
Says that a reference to an mraid.js file should be the first line within an MRAID compliant ad

> MRAID script reference
>   The MRAID comment follows HTML Javascript syntax so that both fully formed web pages and
>   HTML fragments can be identified as MRAID ads.
>
> `<script src="mraid.js"></script>`

Which is ok.  But I am being convinced by some CTO that it is OK for the mraid.js to not exist.  Surely it must exist and contain some function call for confirmation of the existence of the MRAID function requests or initialise the MRAID namespace.

Answer (score 4):

See the following text out of the api spec:

"Ad designers must include the JavaScript identification reference for MRAID, but the actual JavaScript libraries are supplied by the container, and it is the responsibility of the SDK to ensure they are available to the ad in a timely fashion after the script reference is made."

So the answer depends on what you're doing/who you are in the process. If you're designing the ad then you don't have to worry about it.

If you're developing an mobile app that is supposed to display the ad, you have to make sure that your MRAID library/code makes the file available.